# Why using of Inertia in laravel turn working page into whitescreen?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

The stack I'm using: *Laravel*, *Inertiajs*, *Vue.js*.

I am new in using laravel, so I can't get why `composer require laravel/breeze --dev`  and `php artisan breeze:install vue` turn laravel project with *vue.js* into white board. Browser console writes: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**ed.** problem is in `npm install` it compile with such error:

```
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v16.15.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
```

Comment: you will need to run npm install and npm run dev for your assets to be compiled

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things which could be wrong here.

1. If you haven't installed all of the packages necessary for your frameworks nothing will happen. You can do this by running `npm install` in your projects root directory on Laravel.
2. If you are looking to actively develop your site you'll need to enable to webpack/mix compiler for the Laravel frameworks. You can start the watcher with `npm run watch`
3. If you are attempting to deploy your app and it is in a stable state where you do not need to do any active development work you'll want to build the scripts. This will compile all of the packages and minify your files while striping superfluous code used for debugging during development. You can do this with `npm run dev`

It won't be caused by attempting to combine Inertia with Jetstream as [they are made to play nicely with each other.](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/stacks/inertia.html)

Something is going wrong with how your app is hosting up your app.js file or lack thereof.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I didn't noticed that ```npm install``` was finished with issues.
Thanks for additional knowledge about Inertia and Jetstream.

Comment: Did this fix your issue or are you still running into problems?